# Not finding variable within CSV File

Tags: python, csv

So here i am looking for the name "Steve" in my csv file. However it cant find it? (It prints "Not found" to shell indicating that it ran the else statement)

This is my CSV File:

```
Dave    55
Steve   3
Max     56
```

This is my python File:

```
import csv
name = "Steve"
score = "5"
classname = "Class A"

if classname == "Class A":
    f = open('Class A.csv', 'r')
    csvread = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvread:
        if row[0] == name:
            with open('Class A.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
                print("FOUND")
        else:
            with open('Class A.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
                print("NOT FOUND")
```

(My code extends beyond this but this is the issue bit so I'l save you the whole program)

Comment: Did you try `csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')` ? By default, it expects comma as delimiter.

Comment: I ran your script got `>NOT FOUND >FOUND >NOT FOUND` what else were you expecting?

Comment: @mehtunguh Just tried that still not found

Comment: @Leb For it to find the name and only say "Found" and run the code within that

Comment: This is really confusing, you're opening a file to print "FOUND"?

Comment: Or are you trying to *write* to the file "FOUND"?

Comment: What does the csv file use for delimiter? Are those spaces or tabs? They appear to be spaces, which would make it impossible to use csv to parse the columns.

Comment: @Leb I'm opening the file and then looking to see if the variable "Name" is within it. In the example I got it to print "FOUND" but in my full program this would be replaced with the corresponding code

Comment: @mehtunguh I'm pretty sure he's using that format to present it in here. They're not tabs.

Comment: @max.church2000 what is the corresponding code? Writing to file?

Comment: @mehtunguh I'm not sure what you mean, but I havnt edited it so what ever CSV's normally edit by I assume

Comment: @Leb Appending that row instead of a new row, yes

Comment: @mehtunguh CSV is Comma Separated Values, so by default it's commas, unless it was written differently then I'm not sure.

Comment: @max.church2000 I mean the actual file. Can you look at the lines in the file? Are there comma's or something else between the columns?

Comment: @leb I haven't changed anything in the way it was written

Comment: @mehtunguh there are no commas between the lines

Answer (score 1):

Your file doesn't seem to be properly formatted as a CSV.

The most common CSV formatting that you can see is with commas (could be semicolon or have quotes depending on internationalization):

```
Dave,55
Steve,3
Max,56
```

The code to read this CSV would be the following indeed:

```
import csv
f = open('comma_separated.csv', 'r')
csvread = csv.reader(f)
for row in csvread:
    if row[0] == "Steve":
        print("FOUND")
    else:
        print("NOT FOUND")
```

In your "csv" I see no seperator. It looks like a fixed width formatting (meaning it is not a CSV file), meaning the value of each column will always take the same space. You can then split your data just by selecting the column where the data are. Another way could be to use regular expression.

```
f = open('fixed_width.txt', 'r')
for row in f:
    if row[0:5].strip() == "Steve":
        print("FOUND")
    else:
        print("NOT FOUND")
```

As other suggested, if the fields are indeed separated with tabulation the file should look that way (If you copy-paste in a text editor you will have a better chance at seeing the tabulation between the values):

```
Dave    55
Steve   3
Max 56
```

The corresponding code will get you the answer you need with tabulations:

```
import csv
f = open('tab_separated.tsv', 'r')
csvread = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
for row in csvread:
    if row[0] == "Steve":
        print("FOUND")
    else:
        print("NOT FOUND")
```

Also please note that in my examples that I removed the open() of the file in append mode because I don't see the use case of doing so and it was not answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little vague on your expected outcome, but you definitely to change `print("FOUND")` to `fp.write("whatever the output is")`

The way you're opening the file and appending to it at the same time, can be dangerous and not recommended. It's always better to write to a new file to prevent issues.

If you're wanting to write `Steve` to the new file then just `row[0]` if you're wanting to write `Steve 3` then you need to split the list of `("Steve", 3)` before writing. `write()` only allows strings, not a list or tuple.

Let me know if this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Since your file seems to be separated by whitespace instead of a character delimiter, you cannot use `csv.reader` to parse it.

instead of

```
csvread = csv.reader(f)
for row in csvread:
```

try this

```
for line in f:
    row = line.split()
```

this should give the result you are looking for.